# Highlight string interpolations in color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

everyone,

I have a question about string interpolation. Namely, I have built in a text that is to appear in my app strings that were previously defined. Now I wanted to know how I can always highlight this built-in strings in different colors.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Are you looking for `NSAttributedString`? Do you have an example? Else https://alisoftware.github.io/swift/2018/12/16/swift5-stringinterpolation-part2/  ?

Comment: I tried it once as it was written in the instructions. Unfortunately, then come the three mistakes:

Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member ’color' ;

Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member ' red' ;

Extra argument in call

Comment: Show us what code you've already written and tried.